# OpenSceneGraph static linking for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, openscenegraph

I'm trying to compile static OpenSceneGraph for Android. However, when I'm trying to open simple .osg model, osg says that it can't load `osgPlugins-3.4.0/osgdb_osg.so`.

Host OS: macOS 10.12.6

CMake version 3.9.0

OpenSceneGraph version 3.4.0

Android NDK version r14b

CMake configuration:

```
cmake ../OpenSceneGraph \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../OpenSceneGraph-android-static \
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME="Android" \
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=17 \
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=armeabi-v7a \
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/Users/kamil/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle \
-DOPENGL_PROFILE="GLES2" \
-DDYNAMIC_OPENTHREADS=OFF \
-DDYNAMIC_OPENSCENEGRAPH=OFF
```

I'm linking OpenSceneGraph libraries to my project qmake file as follows:

`my-project.pro`:

```
...
LIBS += $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/lib/osgPlugins-3.4.0/libosgdb_osg.a \
        $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/lib/libosgViewer.a \
        $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/lib/libosgDB.a \
        $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/lib/libosgGA.a \
        $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/lib/libosgText.a \
        $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/lib/libosgUtil.a \
        $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/lib/libosgShadow.a \
        $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/lib/libosgTerrain.a \
        $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/lib/libosgSim.a \
        $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/lib/libosg.a \
        $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/lib/libOpenThreads.a

INCLUDEPATH += $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/include

LIBS += $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libcurl.a \
        $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libgdal.a \
        $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libft2.a \
        $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libgif.a \
        $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libjpeg.a \
        $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libpng.a \
        $${OPENSCENEGRAPHPATH}/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libtiff.a
...
```

In my `main.cpp` I've used `USE_OSGPLUGIN` macro to link `osg` plugin:

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <osgDB/Registry>
...
USE_OSGPLUGIN(osg)
...
int main() {
    ...
}
```

However, when I'm trying to open some osg file:

```
osg::Node * node = osgDB::readNodeFile(":/resources/cessna.osg");
```

`osgDB::readNodeFile` returns `NULL` and prints in output:

```
Warning: dynamic library 'osgPlugins-3.4.0/osgdb_osg.so' does not exist (or isn't readable):
dlopen failed: library "osgPlugins-3.4.0/osgdb_osg.so" not found
DynamicLibrary::failed loading "osgPlugins-3.4.0/osgdb_osg.so"
```

What should I do to correctly link OpenSceneGraph library for Android?

Comment: Did you got the solution?

Comment: Yes, it seems that I've found solution. Instead of `USE_OSGPLUGIN(osg)` I've added following lines: `USE_OSGPLUGIN(osg2) USE_SERIALIZER_WRAPPER_LIBRARY(osg)`. I've found solution here: https://github.com/OGStudio/openscenegraph-cross-platform-guide/tree/master/1.8.SampleUnderAndroid. Maybe it will help you.